# React Webpack dynamic file name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint

I have 100 image assets that represent levels that a user could be at (level 1-100). Right now I'm displaying the icon like this with an inline style:

```
const backgroundImg = require(`app/images/levels/${currentLevel}.svg`);

return (
  <div
    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImg})` }}
  />
);
```

What is a better way to require these images based on the user level? (currently throws a import/no-dynamic-require error)

Comment: its eslint error message, you could ignore. There is a cleaner way to do that. let me post.

Comment: check this article, can be helpful https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234

Answer (score 3):

```
const getImagePerLevel = (currentLevel) => {
    return import(`app/images/levels/${currentLevel}.svg`);
}

return (
  <div
    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${getImagePerLevel(currentLevel)})` }}
  />
);
```